# Sync SOME folders between Mac & External HD

Tags: mac, hard-drive, sync

I want to sync selected folders between an external hard disk and my Mac. I used to be able to do this with ease on my PC with Laplink, but I can't do it on my Mac. I purchased Laplink Switch and Sync but it doesn't recognize the external disk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

An another solution is [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/). With it you can easily select folders that you want to sync.

If you are gonna to sync your folders with Time Machine, download [TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/) if you don't want to backup your folders every hour.

Answer (score 0):

**Time Machine** may be a viable solution, depending upon your needs. You can tell TM to ignore certain directories, though this may be impractical if you only need to sync a couple of folders. You can also use a shell script and the cron scheduler to `cp -r` directories to the external drive.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Time machine is the best option to sync your data from your mac computer to the external hard drive.